# Why does my $y$ axis extend below $y=0$?

Tags: plotting, options

I have an issue where my y axis is drawn too far down. I feel like there should be a question out there asking about this, but I wasn't able to find anything. Is there any way to make the y-axis only draw so that it makes a perfect **L** shape with the x axis?

Here is my code:

```
flux[t_] := 
   Sqrt[2/π] (8 + 6 t) Exp[-2*(6 - 2 t)^2/(4 + t^2)]
   /(4 + t^2)^(3/2);

fluxPlot = Plot[flux[t], {t, tMin - dt, tMax + dt},
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0090], GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.8]},
   LabelStyle -> Opacity[0],
   Ticks -> None
   ];

h = Histogram[histPoints, {dt}, "ProbabilityDensity",
   ChartStyle -> GrayLevel[0.88, opacityHist],
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Opacity[opacityHist + 0.15]],
   LabelStyle -> Opacity[0],
   Ticks -> None,
   AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.006]
   ];

Show[h,fluxPlot]
```

And here is the issue, visible in the bottom left corner below the x-axis:

[image]

Comment: Add the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0`?

Comment: what is `flux`?

Comment: Adding PlotRangePadding -> 0 removed the entire y axis. I have edited in the flux function now.

Comment: Update: I was able to fix it by making PlotRangePadding = {0.126, 0.003}. These values were found by just guessing and checking... going too far made the whole axis disappear but not going far enough left that little notch on the bottom. I don't know if there's a more elegant solution or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hstpts = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], 1500];
flx[x_] := PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], x];

plt = Plot[flx[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red];
hist = Histogram[hstpts, Automatic, "PDF"];

Show[plt, hist, plt, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the first `Part` of `hist` as `Prolog` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[flx[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 Prolog -> First @ hist]
```

[image]

Comment: Had to mess around a bit with PlotRangePadding -> {xPadding, yPadding} but ultimately it was the solution :)